# How to display results when the input is empty with Ajax in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a AJAX search input field that searches on multiple field in the retours table.
[image]

On first page load and when the search input is empty it displays all retours where `status = 3`.

Then u type in the search and it runs and returns this code:

```
$searchquery = $request->get('searchqueryfinished');

$data = Retour::where('status', 3)
    ->where(function($q) use($searchquery) {
        $q->where('rma', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
            ->orWhere('naam', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
            ->orWhere('framenummer', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%');
    })->get();
```

If you clear the search input field the whole table is empty, i want it to display all retours where `status = 3`. just like when u first load the page..

I tried checking if $searchquery isset but can't get it to work.

The ajax:

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horinzontal']) !!}
{!! Form::text('search', null, ['id' => 'search-input', 'required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Retourbon zoeken, begin met typen...', 'onkeyup' => 'search_data(this.value, "result")']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script>
function search_data(search_value) {
    console.log(search_value);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{action("RetoursController@searchretour", ["d" => 'd'])}}' ,
        data: {searchqueryfinished:search_value},
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('.ajax-table-retours').html(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just to specify the default value if there's no `searchqueryfinished` received so the `$searchquery` will take `3` as value :

```
$searchquery = $request->get('searchqueryfinished',3);
```

If you receive `searchqueryfinished` and the received value is an empty string `""`, you could use `empty()` method to check and return `3` if true :

```
$searchquery = $request->get('searchqueryfinished');
$searchquery = empty($searchquery)?3:$searchquery;
```

> I need it to return ALL Retour::where('status', 3)->get()->all(); And not filter things.

So you've just to make a condition :

```
if(empty($searchquery)){
    $data = Retour::where('status', 3)->get();
}else{
    $data = Retour::where('status', 3)
        ->where(function($q) use($searchquery) {
            $q->where('rma', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                ->orWhere('naam', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                ->orWhere('framenummer', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%');
        })->get();
}
```

Try this js :

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    if( search_value != ""){
      var option = {searchqueryfinished:search_value};
    }else{
      var option = {};
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{action("RetoursController@searchretour", ["d" => 'd'])}}' ,
        data: option,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $('.ajax-table-retours').html(response);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does'nt fix the problem.. Nothing changed

Comment: With the search query having a default of 3 does not return the records i need. I need it to return ALL Retour::where('status', 3)->get()->all(); And not filter things. I'm sorry if i was being unclear.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i need. but i allready tried it. And it does not work.. I don't know why. When i dd($data); after the condition it returns correct array when search is not empty but returns nothing when $searchresult is empty..

Comment: It doesn't seem to get into the if(empty($searchquery)) of the condition

Comment: So you didn't sent an empty it may a space.. check `dd($searchquery==" "?'space':'not a space')`

Comment: It returns nothing. I think it might have somthing to do with the AJAX i use.. i'll add it into the Post

Comment: Completely blank.

Comment: Try the js in my update with `dd($request->get('searchqueryfinished',3));` in the start of your controller action.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki @JordyGroote There is really no need of so much customization.... The code show really work without the need to check if `searchqueryfinished == ""` or not...

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly build the query such as this:

```
$searchquery = $request->get('searchqueryfinished');

$data = Retour::where('status', 3);
if(!empty($searchquery)) {
    $data = $data->where(function($q) use($searchquery) {
              $q->where('rma', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                ->orWhere('naam', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                ->orWhere('framenummer', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%');
            });
}
$data = $data->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much cleaner and easy to understand

```
$searchquery = $request->get('searchqueryfinished');

$searchquery = trim($searchquery);

if(empty($searchquery)) {
  return Retour::where('status', 3)->get();
}

return Retour::where('status', 3)
             ->where(function($q) use ($searchquery) {
                $q->where('rma', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                  ->orWhere('naam', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
                  ->orWhere('framenummer', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%');
             })
             ->get();
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki @JordyGroote Perhaps the problem is with the JS and not PHP? Are you running an `onkeyup` event for this? If not... please do :)

Comment: @JordyGroote Are you sure you tried my code and its not working?

Comment: Yes i tried it, it seems to never get into the empty condition..  The empty($searchquery) never returns true which is weird.

Comment: @JordyGroote Can you do `dd($searchquery)` before `if()` and tell what you are getting?

Comment: Can you try and comment out `if()` and check if only `return Retour::where('status', 3)->get();` is coming out to be true for any searchqueryfinished?

Comment: This works, but is only triggerd when something is typed in the input field. when the input field has text in it it returns Retour::where('status', 3)->get();.

Comment: @JordyGroote And when you type something and hit backspace... Then? Are you having problems loading the table on load or on the part where text field becomes empty when u hit backspace there?

Comment: When i first load the page it loads the correct records since it's using the RetourController@index which states return Retour::where('status', 3)->get();.  But when i hit backspace when i searched something it is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129276/discussion-between-prateekkathal-and-jordy-groote).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by splitting it up to different ROUTES and into different Public functions.

I made new routes:

```
Route::get('/retoursearchall', 'RetoursController@searchretourall');
Route::get('/retoursearchfinished', 'RetoursController@searchretourfinished');
Route::get('/retoursearchopen', 'RetoursController@searchretouropen');
```

When they we're in different public functions i could check if the input was Empty..

I still don't exactly know what i did wrong, checked for typo's the code was exactly the same but now it seems to work..